# How to scroll my JPanel

Tags: java, swing

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I'm creating a list of bank movements with the following code. pane is a `JPanel` and array is an `ArrayList` that contains respectively amount and description data. Setting is a little icon that allow you to modify each movement.

`MouseClass` is a class that extends `MouseAdapter` that I've created to add "k" index to mouseClicked method. I'm new with java gui programming. I'd like to know if there is a quick method to add a scroll to my panel

```
    JLabel[] movement = new JLabel[array.size()];
    JLabel[] description = new JLabel[array.size()];
    JLabel[] data = new JLabel[array.size()];
    JLabel[] setting = new JLabel[array.size()];

    System.out.println(array.size());


    int i = 0;
    for(int k=0; k<array.size(); k++){
        movement[k] = new JLabel("");
        movement[k].setForeground(SystemColor.text);
        movement[k].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        movement[k].setBounds(17, i, 145, 30);
        movement[k].setText(array.get(array.size() - k - 1).getAmount() + "€");
        panel.add(movement[k]);

        description[k] = new JLabel("");
        description[k].setForeground(SystemColor.text);
        description[k].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        description[k].setBounds(187, i, 274, 30);
        description[k].setText(array.get(array.size() - k - 1).getDescription());
        panel.add(description[k]);

        data[k] = new JLabel("");
        data[k].setForeground(SystemColor.text);
        data[k].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        data[k].setBounds(478, i, 145, 30);
        data[k].setText(array.get(array.size() - k - 1).getDate());
        panel.add(data[k]);

        setting[k] = new JLabel();
        setting[k].setIcon(new ImageIcon(List.class.getResource("/it/andreavaiuso/financemanager/images/edit.png")));
        setting[k].setForeground(SystemColor.text);
        setting[k].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        setting[k].addMouseListener(new MouseClass(array.size() - k - 1) {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                Modify mdf = new Modify(this.index);
                mdf.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
        });
        setting[k].setBounds(640, i, 82, 30);
        panel.add(setting[k]);

        i += 40;



    }
```

But I don't know how to scroll it. I've tried woth JScrollPane but don't work!
I'm sure there is a simplest way to add these items to my panel...

Comment: Add JScrollPane. Add JPanel to the JScrollPane instead of to the JFrame.

Comment: *" I've tried woth JScrollPane but don't work!"* please add your try to the code example

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried woth JScrollPane but don't work!

Well I see lots of code with `setBounds(...)` which implies you are using a null layout.

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. In fact the scroll pane will only work when used with a layout manager because the scroll pane needs to know the preferred size of the panel so it can determine when you use scrollbars.

I would also suggest you should also be using a `JTable` for something like this. It is more efficient because you don't need to create individual components for each row of data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

For a JScrollPane you need, 1 JScrollPane, 1 JList and one DefaultListModel.

First you add your items to DefaultListModel, then you add the model to the JList and then you make a JSCrollPane with passing as argument your JList

Example:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel<String>();


JList list = new JList<String>();
model.addElemenet("1");
model.addElemenet("3");
model.addElemenet("2");
list.setModel(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
```